# how to find the size of the disk that OS is installed on

Tags: linux, rhel, disk, fdisk, lsblk

how to verify the disk size ( the disk that OS is installed on )

we have redhat 7.2

I will give example

```
# disk_os_size=` lsblk | grep sda `
sda                8:0    0   150G  0 disk
├─sda1             8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2             8:2    0 149.5G  0 part


# disk_os_size=` lsblk | grep sda | awk '{print $4}' `
# echo $disk_os_size
150G 500M 149.5G
```

so in that case the results are not good, because we get also the OS partitions

and what we want is only the size of the disk of the OS that should be 150G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
disk_os_size=$(lsblk /dev/sda -o SIZE -n|head -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `df -h /` or `findmnt -D /` or `findmnt -P / | sed -nr -e 's~.* SOURCE="([^"]*)" .*~\1~p' | xargs lsblk`.